# Custom conditional in Handlebar Template

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I have created the following Handlebar template

```
<script type="text/template" id="status">
{{#completed status}}
     <button class="btn btn-inverse">Close</button>
     <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
{{else}}
     <button class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>
{{/completed}}
</script>
```

Here is my handlebar register helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('completed',function(item,options){
if (item == 'INITIATED'){
    console.log(options.fn())
    return options.fn();        
}
else{
    console.log(options.inverse());
    return options.inverse();
} 
});
```

And my javascript

```
obj={status: 'INITIATED'} and obj={status:'RECEIVED'}
Handlebars.compile( $('#status').html() )(obj).appendTo('body')
```

the `status` variable in the template can have values `INITIATED` or `RECEIVED/COMPLETED`

When I print in the console, I am getting the excepted buttons( once, the 3 buttons and the next time the one button) but in the html file I am getting the `else section` only( both the times ).

I am not sure where I have gone wrong. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your template and helper are fine. The way you're using them:

```
Handlebars.compile( $('#status').html() )(obj).appendTo('body')
```

doesn't make sense though. `Handlebars.compile` returns a function, calling that function produces a string; that means that your `appendTo` actually looks like this:

```
var tmpl = Handlebars.compile($('#status').html());  // Okay
var html = tmpl(obj);                                // Okay
html.appendTo('body');                               // Broken.
```

Strings don't have `appendTo` methods. You could wrap a `$()` around the string:

```
$(
    Handlebars.compile($('#status').html())(obj)
).appendTo('body');
```

or do it step by step to make the code clearer:

```
var tmpl = Handlebars.compile($('#status').html());
$('body').append(tmpl(obj));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/46sfd/

Comment: sorry. a typing mistake. I have wrapped the string in `$()` before appending in my code. Forgot when i edited here. The template compiles fine and attaches to the body without any issues. The return from the `registerhelper` is the one that doesnot make sense to me though

Comment: I don't understand what doesn't make sense. If `status` is `'INITIATED'` then you get *Close*, *Submit*, and *Delete* buttons otherwise you only get *Close*; that's exactly what the code says and what it does. Maybe if your question contained real runnable code I'd be able to tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: My real template is around 40 lines. I did not want to paste the entire thing. I am generating twitter bootstrap modal in the template. The above one is usually placed in the modal-footer. You are right, though. When the above template is executed as an independent one, I get the expected output. But when I place it in the bootstrap's modal-footer and If I run the template by passing 10 objects, I am getting only the close button in all of them. Sorry again for not pasting the entire thing here. Did not think the issue might be related to me using the modal.

Comment: Can you produce a simplified version on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is my first time using jsfiddle. I copied the code line by line without any change to jsfiddle. It is working fine there and that helped me identify the issue. I am such an idiot. `For all the modals I had kept the same id`. So when I click on different buttons they were all calling the same modal. Can't believe I spent nearly 8 hours on this without noticing this. thank you so much @mu for the help